# Jquery select textarea based on value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, textarea

I'm trying to select textareas based on the value in them, I tried doing this:

```
alert( $('textarea[value="Type"]').length );
```

But I get zero.

Here's my textarea:

```
<textarea id="Title" name="title" rows="5" cols="29" class="textentry_verdana12pxItalic">Type</textarea>
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`value` is not an attribute of that textarea. That textarea's HTML attributes are `id`, `name`, `rows`, `cols`, and `class`. Try this instead:

```
$('textarea').filter(function ()
{
    return $(this).val() === 'Type';
}).length
```

[`.filter()` API docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

Comment: does not say that is exactly the value

Comment: @andres: but that's exactly what the `value="Type"` selector does, so it makes sense to conclude, as @Matt does, that that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "contains" pseudo selector:

```
jQuery('textarea:contains(Type)')
```

Comment: That will return all textareas which contain the word `Type` anywhere in their value. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: True, it will. He didn't specify exactly, so I offered it up.

Comment: The selector in the question implies "exactly," whether or not that was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    alert( $('textarea:contains("Type")').length );

Comment: That will return all textareas which contain the word `Type` anywhere in their value. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

try this ([contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)):

```
alert($("textarea:contains('Type')").length);
```

Comment: That will return all textareas which contain the word `Type` anywhere in their value. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: does not say that is exactly the value

Comment: As I commented on [JAAulde's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264994/jquery-select-textarea-based-on-value/5265039#5265039): the selector in the question implies "exactly."